# Test deleteById on JpaRepository does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have issue with calling `deleteById` in @DataJpaTest. Tried many solutions from similar questions, but nothing helped.  Here is Entity:

**Entity:**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Project parent;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Project> subProjects = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**JpaRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long>{
}
```

**Test**

```
@Test
    void givenParentAndChilds_whenDeleteParent_thenDeleteChilds() {
        // Given
        Project parent = Project.builder().name("parent").build();
        parent = projectRepository.save(parent);
        
        Project child1 = Project.builder().name("child1").build();
        child1.setParent(parent);
        child1 = projectRepository.save(child1);
        
        Project child2 = Project.builder().name("child2").build();
        child2.setParent(parent);
        child2 = projectRepository.save(child2);
        
        Project child3 = Project.builder().name("child3").build();
        child3.setParent(parent);
        child3 = projectRepository.save(child3);
        
        assertTrue(projectRepository.findById(parent.getId()).isPresent());
        assertTrue(projectRepository.findById(child1.getId()).isPresent());
        assertTrue(projectRepository.findById(child2.getId()).isPresent());
        assertTrue(projectRepository.findById(child3.getId()).isPresent());
        
        // When
        projectRepository.deleteById(parent.getId());
        
        // Then
        assertFalse(projectRepository.findById(parent.getId()).isPresent());
        assertFalse(projectRepository.findById(child1.getId()).isPresent()); // <-- these assertions fails
        assertFalse(projectRepository.findById(child2.getId()).isPresent());
        assertFalse(projectRepository.findById(child3.getId()).isPresent());
    }
```

During test child items are not deleted by cascading. I tried following things:

1. Add `orphanRemoval = true` to `@OneToMany` annotation in `Project` entity
2. Add `deleteById` with `@Transactional` in `ProjectRepository`
3. Add `@Transactional` as test annotation

None of above works, childs cannot be deleted. In Spring Boot logs `DELETE` query is missing too. What is wrong with my test?

Answer (score 2):

Solution was to properly set bi-directional linkage between `parent` and `childs`:

```
    public void setParent(Project parent){
        this.parent = parent;
        parent.getSubProjects().add(this);
    }
```